# Refresh Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to insert a value in the database and update the recyclerview automatically.
I have this block of code to insert into the database.

```
.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    int PessoaNova = aula.getPessoas();
                                    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
                                    int resultado = aula.getId();
                                    PessoaNova = aula.getPessoas() + 1;
                                    dbHelper.AlterarPessoa(resultado, PessoaNova);
```

And the code I use to update the list is this

```
swipeRefreshLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayou);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                db = new DBHelper(getContext());
                aulasDAO = new AulasDAO(getContext());
                aulas = aulasDAO.getAulas();
                recyclerViewAulasAdapter = new RecyclerViewAulasAdapter(aulas,getContext());
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAulasAdapter);
                recyclerViewAulasAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```

I wanted the list to update automatically when the user clicked the button

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: I click on the button and add a person to the class and then I like that list updates automatically.